# How codepad know about infinite loop?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, codepad

I tried the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<50;i++){
    printf("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i;
    while(1){
    printf("Hello World");
    }
}
```

codepad shows "Time out". Does it have syntax-checks or does it simply check if my program takes up too much time?

Comment: what do you mean by `how to do` ?

Comment: How to check infinite loop like codepad.

Comment: Without a `'\n'` in the output (or a explicit `fflush(stdout);`) the output may be "stuck" in a buffer and you never see it in the 2nd case. **WARNING: before the code times out, it may print several megabytes worth of "Hello World"s**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like codepad has limits for resources used by submitted programs, and stops the ones that are beyond them.

Your infinite loop program exceeds the time limit, and is stopped with "Time out" message. So there's nothing related to syntax checking here.

Comment: Is it use function set_time_limit in php or script in bash/batch?
and how to parallel program between timer and program.c?

Comment: Ask a question specific to this. Can't help you on this as I don't know php.